# Extract fixed value from certain column in mysql corresponding to the date

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i have a table in Mysql which has two column **date** and **total number**.i want to extract the total number on current date by writing query.so that i could use the total number for further calculation.thanks in advance

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server = localhost; User Id = root; Password=;Database=project"
    Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()

        Dim todaysdate As String = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", DateTime.Now)
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from project.total_number where date=DateTime.Now"
        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        Reader = Command.ExecuteReader
        MessageBox.Show("data saved")
        MysqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()

    End Try
```

i have done so far but Datetime.Now is showing error.i want to use the result of the query in the calculation

Answer (score 0):

You are using `DateTime.Now` in your `WHERE` condition (`where date=DateTime.Now`) as if it's a string literal and that's why the error you are receiving. Change it to below

```
Query = "select * from project.total_number where `date`=" & DateTime.Now;
```

(OR) Better use a parameterized query to avoid SQL Injection like

```
Query = "select * from project.total_number where `date`= @dateval"
Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
With Command
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateval", DateTime.Now)
End With
```